# Baby kitten demands more food but has a big belly

Tags: cats, diet, strays

My kitten’s belly is big and I give her a good amount of food at a time, but afterwards she wants more. She plays and behaves otherwise normal. Should I feed her more?

She is four weeks old and she is a stray kitten. Her body weight is 280 g.

[image]

Comment: Not part of your question, but: you do massage her belly gently after feeding to help her pee and poop? And I would recommend you register your account, that makes for example editing your question easier (or even possible) and we can help you and the kitten better.

Comment: You should also feed her special food for kittens. She is very young and must grow a lot, so she needs a special diet with all the vitamins and minerals that help her body grow. Please buy kitten food for 4 - 6 weeks old kittens at your local pet store or online.

Comment: With kittens younger than weaning age (6-8 weeks), they require special care. I'd suggest consulting resources for care of neonatal kittens (for instance, Kitten Lady's website) to learn about the additional care needed beyond that for weaned kittens.

Comment: Stray? Have a veterinarian check her stool for worms.

Answer (score 2):

Some kittens don’t know when to stop eating. Their portions should be measured. A big belly can also mean parasites or a medical problem that needs vet attention. An extended belly  on a kitten is always reason for concern. Kitten Lady is a great resource but doesn’t replace vet care. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Two potential issues concern me.

First is parasites. This will make the kitten always hungry, as they steal nutrients and cause bloated bellies.

Second, I also worry about wet FIP, which usually shows with bloating in the belly as it fills with fluid. However, they usually show other signs such as weight loss and lethargy as well (but not always).

After eating, does the kitten's belly size go down? A belly is normal on kittens, and should make their body shape like an avocado or eggplant (not like a sagging water balloon).

I would schedule a vet visit. Routine check-ups generally aren't very expensive. Most likely, the vet will just give you peace of mind, but if it does turn out to be FIP there is now treatment for it. Vets can't administer or recommend it, but the Facebook group FIP Warriors 5.0 can help you access it. Without treatment, FIP is fatal.